# Skip to the next index in a for loop with thread after a given time

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop

I'm trying to make a program that creates a vocabulary from a file .txt. It takes a file, creates a document (a String), splits that document in sentences and finally, for each sentence it does some operation (tokenization, pos tagging, costituents tree parsing etc.).

Sometime the program stops on a sentences (that's bad for me), so what I would do is to **avoid to stay on a sentence too time** (let's suppose 120s).
If so, the program should go to the next sentence in the list.

I thought to use a thread and a timer and check if that time is passed, but I'm confused on how to use the thread.

Here part of my code:

```
public class Vocabulary {
    private Thread thread;
    private long sentenceDuration;
    private Queue<File> corpus;

    public Vocabulary(){
        this.sentenceDuration = 0;           
        corpus = loadCorpus();
    }

    public void buildVocabulary(){

        for (File f : corpus) {
                Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(f.getPath()));

                // Create a string representing the document
                String document = "";
                while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                    document += in.nextLine() + " ";
                }
                in.close();

                // Split the document in sentences
                ArrayList<String> sentences = tpr.documentToSentences(document);

                for (int i = 0; i < sentences.size(); i++) {
                    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, timer());
                    timer.start();

                    while(sentenceDuration < 120){      // while it takes under 120 seconds to compute the sentence, ok.

                        List<CoreLabel> tokens = tpr.tokenize(sentences.get(i));        // tokenize the sentence
                        Tree parse = tpr.apply(tokens);                                 // create the costituents tree
                        Object[] basicDependencies = tpr.getBasicDependencies(parse);   // get the basic dependencies from the tree

                        // some operations here...             

                        Thread.sleep(1000);     // 1000 ms
                    }

                    // when it takes over 120 seconds to compute the sentence, jump to the next sentence 
                    System.out.println("Hey, I took long time to compute the sentence. I'm going to the next one!");
                }  

                // Other operations here...
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        end();
        this.thread = new Thread(this);
        this.thread.start();
    }

    public void end() {
       if (thread != null && thread.isAlive()) {
            thread.interrupt();
        }
    }

    private ActionListener timer() {

        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sentenceDuration++;
            }
        };
        return taskPerformer
    }   
}
```

In the main I simply call:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Vocabulary().start();     
 }
```

How can I say to the program: "if 120s are passed, skip the sentence!". That is, "exit the while loop immediatly! No matter what operation you're doing." ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so scratch the Semaphore, a simple join() will do. Something like:

```
// Split the document in sentences
ArrayList<String> sentences = tpr.documentToSentences(document);

for (int i = 0; i < sentences.size(); i++) {
    SentenceProcessorThread sentenceProcessorThread = new SentenceProcessorThread(sentences.get(i));
    sentenceProcessorThread.start();
    try {
        sentenceProcessorThread.join(120000); // your timeout period goes here
        if (sentenceProcessorThread.isAlive()) {
            sentenceProcessorThread.interrupt();
            System.out.println("aborting thread");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException x) {
    }
}
```

Throw your sentence processing logic in it's own thread:

```
class SentenceProcessorThread extends Thread {
    private String sentence;

    public SentenceProcessorThread(String sentence) {
        this.sentence = sentence;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            // your sentence processing logic goes here
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. this is the way I'm taking. But, can I ask you to make to me an example extending your answer? I never used Semaphores.

Comment: I'll update my answer when I can get to an IDE so that I can give you a working example

Comment: As I understood tryAcquire serves to acquire a resocurce, and so tryAcquire(120) simply wait for 120 s before leave the request. join() is likely what I need...the thread must do its operations, and if 120 elapsed, than it must die! 
Your answer is simple and concise. Thank you!